# ScrollView issue...need to jump to exact location

Tags: iphone, ipad

Scrollviewcustomcontrol not sending correct ID to display the desired output. We have two textviews showing 4 articles snippets in scrollview. They are subviews of scrollview. Now clicking on them, I wish to open a details page of that article along with scroller so that all news could be browsed/scrolled in full form. ScrollerView is in place, working with paging, and showing all the records from beginning. Its just not going to the exact article that we clicked. 
I tried to pass values via textviews and buttons assigned to it. But it can just pass two values since we have two textviews..and there are four articles..article number 3 is passing the ID of article number 1. And article number 4 is passing the ID of article number 2.
Any ideas?

```
    - (IBAction) tappedItemAtIndex:(id)sender {

UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*) sender;
NSInteger selectedIndex = [tappedButton tag];
```

}

```
    int j=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowOne.count; i++) {

        if (j==1) {

            j++;


        }

        count =i+1;
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    UIView*subView=[[UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subView];

    CGRect myframe=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128);        

    //CGRect myframe=CGRectMake(13, 46, 352, 128);
    Book*book=[rowOne objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton*backViewButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

     backViewButton.frame=CGRectMake(107, 46, 258, 128);    
    [backViewButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



        buttontitle=book.title;

        [backViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
        [backViewButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backViewButton setTitle:buttontitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [subView addSubview:backViewButton];


        backViewButton.tag=j;


        j++;

        Book*book1=[rowOneSecond objectAtIndex:i];
        UIButton*backViewButton1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        backViewButton1.frame=CGRectMake(531, 99, 300, 100);    
        [backViewButton1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        NSString*title=book1.title;

        backViewButton1.tag=j;

        [backViewButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedItemAtIndex:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
        [backViewButton1 setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [subView addSubview:backViewButton1];                                               

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try setting tag to the textViews. Like when you add them in scrollview I assume you run a loop so add textView to a button and then add that button to scrollview and assign tag = index(loop increment variable). Add target to button. From there you can get the tag of button and then you pass it to super class by creating a delegate protocol.

**Update**

//I assume you have this type of function bound to each button's touchUpInside.

```
- (IBAction) tappedItemAtIndex:(id)sender {
    UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton*) sender;
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [tappedButton tag];

}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response Rahul.

Comment: Should I add 4 buttons or just two buttons? Because I have to display four values. And we have two pages in scroll view.. so items are shown in the set of twos. First it shows snippet of two items and than upon scroll it shows next two items.

Comment: wouldn't that be the same thing? Two buttons will have four textviews (1 each). Button number 1 and 3 will send value of 3 and button number 2 and 4 will send value of 4..taking the last value in loop of page.

Comment: @Omar no you are not understanding. For each item add one button below that so that you can identify which item no tapped by their index. Index means assign unique tag to them.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for the help..I created the buttons with unique IDs ..those IDs can be used as index .. Can you guide me how I can parse int argument from button to TouchUPInSide Event? I am getting this error "Unrecognized Selector Sent"

Comment: @Rahul please check the updated code in question. I tried your function and I feel I am very very close. But for some reason your method is always showing 0 as the value of tab. What can be the issue? Any logical errors?

Comment: @Omar try to debug your app and see if tag is correctly assigned or not. also you are assigning same target to two different buttons.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks for all your help and hints. I was able to complete the app. Though its still not ready for production but should be good enough for demo. What I am still missing associating tag with text. Title of the article and its image is perfectly working and taking us to exact details page as both are buttons (image and title) ..but no clue how I can associate text

Comment: @Omar you need to create a data modal which contains all the detail you need. Like title,image,text will be in a data modal. so when you get the index of selected item get that object from array pass the array to delegate method you have created.

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to the content based on pages, store a pageNumber in your scrollerview. When you press "next page" button or somehow scroll to the next page, increment the page number and then every time you are loading a page call:

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    // textViews is an NSArray of the 2 textviews you have in your scroller view
    // articles is an NSArray in scrollerview containing all articles as strings
    unsigned int i, article;
    for(i = 0; i < [textViews count]; ++i)
    {
        article = pageNumber*[textViews count]+i;
        if(article < [articles count])
        {
            [(UITextView *)[textViews objectAtIndex:i]
             setText:[articles objectAtIndex:article]];
        } else {
            [(UITextView *)[textViews objectAtIndex:i]
             setText:@""]; // blank pages, because we're at the end
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are just two textviews available for four items. Even if I assign tag to them, they will only get tags..last one in the loop. First and Second items will be missed. Clicking on both first and third will direct to 3rd article and clicking on second and fourth item will direct to 4th article. There are just two textviews whose text is changed when we scroll.

Comment: OK I see what you are asking now.

Answer (score 0):

There is property of UIScrollView contentOffSet,

CGPointMake which is the exact point you need to jump

```
scrollView.contentOffSet = CGPointMake();
```

its helpful for you, i had implement earlier..

Comment: Hello Jagdish! Jumping to a specific location is in control at the moment, passing the correct value or knowing where to jump is the actual issue. We have two textviews holding four articles. They switch the content between pages. Two pages in scroll. How do we adjust these to pass the correct values? Right now two textviews are able to send just two values..last ones in the loop..3 and 4..